# IllegalStateException while selecting item in a listview of a tab

Tags: android, android-listview, illegalstateexception

I am using tabs, and displaying the content in custom listview, after selecting the tab, scrolling on the list and selecting any item of the list causing me below error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has
>   changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the
>   content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but
>   only from the UI thread.

How to solve the issue?

Comment: can you please post some code or logcat output

Answer (score 0):

If the modification of the Collection is taking place in a thread, update the collection inside the runOnUIThread method. Also call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() method.

Answer (score 0):

It was called when your dataset is changed, for example executed list.clear() or other

My suggest is do this in a Thread and use a templist, after the job is done, call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

hope useful to you